# Startup is really slow for all Cygwin applications

Tags: windows, cygwin, windows-8.1

Start of any Cygwin application takes **more than a minute** on Windows 8.1 x64. It doesn't matter, either I'm starting `mintty` from shortcut or `cygwin.bat` or `ls.exe` or `bash.exe` from bin folder. Each of them will be slow.

After Bash or mintty is started they are working fairly quick:

```
$ time for i in {1..10} ; do bash -c "echo Hello" ; done
Hello
...
Hello

real    0m1.273s
user    0m0.060s
sys     0m1.181s
```

Steps, which I've tried:

- Reinstalled and tried both Cygwin and Cygwin64 a few times (version 2.864)
- Started them as Administrator
- Tried to run them in Windows 7 compatibility mode
- Disabled "Automatically detect settings" for LAN [as in this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12466037/515835)
- Added `127.0.0.1 localhost cygdrive wpad` to hosts [as in same reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12466037/515835)
- Set antivirus to disabled state
- Checked that Bash completion is not installed (no `/etc/bash_completion.d` folder)
- Disabled all removable drives in Device Manager (only system SSD and data HDD left)
- Tried to run with empty `etc/profile.d` folder
- Tried to run with empty `etc/bash.bashrc` file

How else can I find root cause?

P.S. -
I have two different systems, laptop and desktop both with Windows 8.1 64 bit. This issue it 100% reproducible on both.

Also, if I start Bash a few seconds after login it starts immediately.

Comment: When network adapted is disabled, cygwin start in a moment. So, it tries to connect to some network resource.

Comment: Network monitor shows massive network activity for cygwin applications. They accessing some machines from my network to LDAP ports via TCP and LDAPMessage.

Comment: I have same problem.  I tried both Solution 1 and Solution 2 below, and neither resolved the problem.  BTW, when I run "mkpasswd", I get an extremely long list in my organization.

Comment: @Hugues most probably you forgot `-c` flag for mkpasswd. In the end, you must get only one line to be saved to `passwd` file. Same for `mkgroup`.

Comment: I did include the `-c` flag when attempting solution 1; both `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` are single-line files.  I was just reporting the fact that the cause of the slowness might be due to the fact that my organization has a long user list (`mkpasswd | wc -l` reports >50K lines)

Comment: @Huhues I'm also working in giant company ;) Sorry, didn't got what you've meant in your first comment.

Comment: In my case my DC was announcing 2 IP addresses. One of them was not reachable from that computer. It was trying to reach port 135/tcp half of the times.

Comment: Possibly related: *[Cygwin from Windows is very slow/ laggy](https://superuser.com/questions/877051)*

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Eventually I found what causes this issue, but I'm still not sure why. Cygwin works for other people in same environment very well.

**Cause:** On the start of every Cygwin application it tries to get credentials as it is described in `etc/nsswitch.conf` file. For some reason, it takes a lots of time for my account as it contacts with several Active Directory domain controllers via LDAP.

**Solution 1:** You can save the current user and group in `etc/passwd` and `etc/group` files and set Cygwin to check them before Active Directory.

1. Start `mintty.exe` and wait till it opens
2. Run `mkpasswd -c` and save its output to `etc/passwd` file (you will have to create it, output should be one line)
3. Run `mkgroup -c` and save its output to `etc/group` file (you will have to create it, output should be one line)
4. Open `etc/nsswitch.conf` and write

nsswitch.conf contents:

```
passwd: files # db
group:  files # db
```

Now your Cygwin should start immediately.

**Solution 2:** There is special [CygServer](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygserver.html) application, shipped with Cygwin, which can be started as an NT service or as a simple process (just run `usr/sbin/cygserver.exe`). It caches credentials and propagates them to every next Cygwin process *while cygserver is running*.

Add it to startup or start it before your Cygwin session and you're good — cygserver startup will take time, but every next Cygwin process will start immediately.

**Is it your case?** I want to share my investigation steps, so you could check, if your case is same to mine.

- Install [MS Network Monitor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) as it is able to show traffic from a specific process. Run it as administrator.
- Create *New capture tab* and click *Start* (you don't have to add any filters or anything).
- Start `mintty` and you will see its connections in netmon: [image: netmon-screenshot]
- You will see list of `mintty` connections in the tree view on the left and TCP and LDAP frames on the right after selecting on of those connections.
- Additionally, you can get name of those remote machines by IP address. Run `nbtstat -a 8.8.8.8` in command line (replace 8.8.8.8 by one of IP addresses from netmon).

**Going deeper:** I'm still playing with [etc/nsswitch.conf](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-mapping-nsswitch) file to get local credentials or maybe cached ones so it will run faster without cygserver. But no luck yet.

Comment: The release notes for the latest version of Cygwin highlight this change. See https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2015-02/msg00009.html

Comment: Hi, I found this thread and wanted to say that I'm also having similar issues that are driving me crazy. Before I post a question, I wanted to get some ideas on whether I'm running into the same issue. Basically, I'm running W7 joined to my company domain. After a recent cygwin update I'm having really long startup times for cygwin terminals, they're taking around 1 to 2 minutes to come up!! This is really frustrating. I'll start reading the thread suggested in the previous comment.

Comment: @JoseCifuentes I recommend you to try out **solution 2** (which is simply start `usr/sbin/cygserver.exe`, wait till it loaded and run any other cygwin application in parallel). If it helps - use solution 1, as it takes longer go trough but cures the problem for sure.

Comment: Thank you! I tried solution 1 and it didn't work (not sure what I did wrong), but solution 2 did work for me. It does take about 2 to 3 seconds for the actual prompt to appear (guess it's running some scripts, etc...) but I can live with that.

Comment: Shouldn't solution 1 be _passwd: files # db_ (don't query SAM/AD) as suggested in the other answer? At least for me merely creating local files but leaving db active in nsswitch.conf does not fix the problem.

Comment: @Tensberg it should work if you have `files` before `db`, as cygwin depends on their order and it works for me. But for the sake of verification you can comment/remove `db` entirely, yes.

Comment: Folks, I've been using Solution #2 for a while. Thanks so much for that. In case someone else hits the same problem, I've seen cases where the cygwin terminals won't start and show this message: _/sbin/nologin: No such file or directory_ .The solution is to restart cygserver. Right click cmd.exe icon, Run As Administrator, and run these two commands:
`sc stop cygserver`
`sc start cygserver`

Comment: solution number 1 worked like a charm also on mingw shipped with git, thank you very much!

(yes it seems to be linked to PC being part of domain)

Answer (score 25):

Here's what worked for me.

1. Launch Cygwin terminal and then run the following two strings.

   ```
   mkpasswd -c > /etc/passwd
   mkgroup -c > /etc/group
   ```
2. Edit your "/etc/nsswitch.conf" file to contain the following two lines.

   ```
   passwd:   files # db
   group:    files # db
   ```
3. Relaunch Cygwin.

Cygwin opens quickly.

Answer (score 7):

If you are on a network with a large AD directory mkpasswd will take a lot of time (several days in my case). So consider using:

```
mkpasswd -c -l > /etc/passwd
mkgroup -c -l > /etc/group

 -l,--local [machine]    Print local user accounts of \"machine\",
                         from local machine if no machine specified.
                         Automatically adding machine prefix for local
                         machine depends on settings in /etc/nsswitch.conf.
```

Comment: Does it takes so much time with -c flag only for you? Also, don't forget to edit nsswitch.conf, as mentioned in other answers.

Comment: Worked for me .. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Adding 'C:\cygwin64\bin' to the path worked for me.