# GCC 3.4.3/Cygwin - slowness

Tags: gcc, dll, cygwin, 64-bit, elf

I have a GCC 3.4.3 toolchain built for ARM (arm-elf) here in my Windows 7 (64bits) setup. We use this to build our software product to a specific hardware.

Recently, we have been experiencing some problems with this particular toolchain.

First, when we try to call arm-elf-gcc to build each source file (there are lots of them), it complained about it not being able to allocate enough heap.

Then, I thought it was some problem with the outdated cygwin DLL distributed by the hardware vendor. So I replaced it with a more recent version (1.7.35). The problem stopped and the build does go ok but now it is incredibly SLOW (it took about 40s to build a single .c source file).

Does anyone has experienced this problem before? How can I debug and fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Please post the answer if you did

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have had a similar problem to me and might be worth trying this.  When i first encountered this, I had to install cygserver and then run this (make sure you right click admin):

[Previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410852/startup-is-really-slow-for-all-cygwin-applications)

**However**, the problem resumed and I simultaneously couldn't install/uninstall some problems.  Eventually I resolved this by terminating SearchIndexer.exe in Task Manager.  Indeed, I have gone in to Control Panel / Searach Indexing and pulled it back from doing any indexing.  My installation taking 1hr took 3 more seconds.  The change to Cygwin was instantaneous.

Cygwin is now flying!

Answer (score 0):

I've had an issue with slow execution of builds for a while on cygwin, using make and a proprietary compiler that "isn't gcc, honest...", but has very similar error returns.

I was forced to update yesterday and ran into the issue of rebaseall simply failing to execute. This forced me to dig into other things and I found a report that Trusteer Rapport/End Point Protection has been known to cause issues with rebaseall,and slow response times.  So I removed it. This fixed the rebaseall, but has also massively increased the speed of my build. Worth checking to see if you have it installed, try removing it. AV packages in general are reputed to interfere and may be the cause.