# cygwin1.dll + own compiled C program runs slow

Tags: performance, dll, cygwin

i want to use a own C program build with cygwin but sometimes it's realy slow to start execute. I want to execute it alone in any windows 10 pc without the rest cygwin files.

i read FAQ's about the Directory Acces timings problem:
[Why does Cygwin execute shell commands very slowly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811435/why-does-cygwin-execute-shell-commands-very-slowly/6811487#6811487)
... but how can i solve the problem if i only have my exe file and the cygwin1.dll?

thanks

Comment: to build a stand alone program, probably mingw is more indicated than cygwin.

Comment: I mean, how slow is "slow"?  Windows executables are inherently heavier-weight and slower to start up than, say, Linux executables. And executables linked to the Cygwin DLL are slower still due to some of the overhead it imposes, especially on first run.  I think without better specificity there is no way to answer your question usefully.