# why is cygwin so slow

Tags: linux, cygwin

I run a script on Ubuntu, and tested its time:

```
$ time ./merger
./merger  0.02s user 0.03s system 99% cpu 0.050 total
```

it spent less than 1 second.
but if I used cygwin:

```
$ time ./merger
real    3m22.407s
user    0m0.367s
sys     0m0.354s
```

It spent more than 3 minutes. 
Why did this happen? What shall I do to increase the executing speed on cygwin?

Comment: Spawning processes on Windows is very slow compared to Linux - there is not much that cygwin can do to get around this limitation.

Comment: Check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835775/msysgit-bash-is-horrendously-slow-in-windows-7) helps.

Comment: @PaulR but I don't think it is as slow to result in a 3min lag. I think there were other processes running in windows when the OP tried this. Or he used something which is significantly different in windows and Linux inside his program.

Comment: It's not just the spawning of processes, but the emulation of `fork` which makes Cygwin so slow. `fork` is something that is not natively supported under the Win32 API, so it has to do a lot of hackery and copying to get the same effect as under POSIX (normally this is done by copying the page table and making the pages copy-on-write, and that's it).

Comment: can you show us the code?, what language are you using? is it a bash script? does it have a big loop? without more information it's hard to help you, @PaulR is right tho, AFAIK fork is slow and even frequently fails under some conditions

Comment: The bash script called some binary files compiled by g++ on linux platform. So it failed on cygwin. Thank you for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to speed up Cygwin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512892/how-to-speed-up-cygwin)

Answer (score 3):

As others have already mentioned, [Cygwin's implementation](https://www.cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.api.fork) of fork and process spawning on Windows in general are slow.

Using [this fork() benchmark](https://github.com/mondalaci/fork-benchmark/blob/master/fork-benchmark.c), I get following results:

```
rr-@cygwin:~$ ./test 1000
Forked, executed and destroyed 1000 processes in 5.660011 seconds.

rr-@arch:~$ ./test 1000
Forked, executed and destroyed 1000 processes in 0.142595 seconds.

rr-@debian:~$ ./test 1000
Forked, executed and destroyed 1000 processes in 1.141982 seconds.
```

Using `time (for i in {1..10000};do cat /dev/null;done)` to benchmark process spawning performance, I get following results:

```
rr-@work:~$ time (for i in {1..10000};do cat /dev/null;done)
(...) 19.11s user 38.13s system 87% cpu 1:05.48 total

rr-@arch:~$ time (for i in {1..10000};do cat /dev/null;done)
(...) 0.06s user 0.56s system 18% cpu 3.407 total

rr-@debian:~$ time (for i in {1..10000};do cat /dev/null;done)
(...) 0.51s user 4.98s system 21% cpu 25.354 total
```

Hardware specifications:

- **cygwin**: `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770K CPU @ 3.50GHz`
- **arch**: `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz`
- **debian**: `Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T5270 @ 1.40GHz`

So as you see, no matter what you use, Cygwin will always operate worse. It loses hands down even to worse hardware (`cygwin` vs. `debian` in this benchmark, as per [this comparison](http://cpuboss.com/cpus/Intel-Core2-Duo-T5270-vs-Intel-Core-i7-3770K)).