# C - MPI Slow Performance

Tags: c, performance, cygwin, mpi

I am trying to learn MPI and running into slow performance using MPI on Windows on my laptop (i5-4260U and 4 GB of RAM). I have installed Cygwin and the appropriate libraries for MPI. I am also using CLion and set up MPI using [this guide](https://github.com/lukasMega/other/wiki/mpi_clion_win).

I have successfully built the code on CLion as well as compiling it on MPICC. However, when I use MPI Run, the program takes a very long time to run. When I run the program normally without using mpirun, it runs just fine. Even when I specify only 1 process, the program still takes over a minute to print out "Hello World".

Is my laptop the reason for the slow performance or have I not setup MPI correctly to get optimal performance? Thanks!

Code:

```
/*Simple MPI Hello World Program*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int node;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &node);

    printf("Hello World from Node %d\n",node);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(MPI_Example)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)
add_executable(MPI_Example ${SOURCE_FILES})

# Require MPI for this project:
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS} ${MPI_COMPILE_FLAGS})
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS} ${MPI_LINK_FLAGS})
include_directories(${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})
target_link_libraries(MPI_Example ${MPI_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Definately not your programe or build options. Not normal. Probably [cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032161/why-is-cygwin-so-slow) but hard to tell.

Comment: @Zulan That is probably it. Unfortunately, I don't know how to configure MinGW with MPICH2 on CLion so I am most likely stuck with this for the time being. Thanks for the help!

Comment: if a firewall is running, start by disabling it. then make sure all your interfaces get resolved (e.g. all IP has hostname and the other way around)

Comment: Is ditching cygwin an option for you? I believe there are native implementations of MPI for Windows.

Comment: @Zulan I do have a old laptop that has Ubuntu on it. I plan to try using that since the slow performance will hinder me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely issue is a network/virtual interface timeout.
Try disabling WIFI network or VPN interface as test.

For reference of expected timing for MPI hello you can see

https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2016-12/msg00192.html

Comment: You mean disabling Wi-Fi on my laptop? If so, I did that and I ran into the following error: `[[24995,1],0] tcp_peer_send_blocking: send() to socket 12 failed: Transport endpoint is not connected (128).` This did occur almost immediately as I ran the program.

Comment: Figured it out. Disabling my Wi-Fi network as well as my Bluetooth network did the trick. The program runs as fast as it should now. Thank you for the help!

Comment: May be it is only the Bluetooth

Comment: It seems to be both the Bluetooth Network Connection 2 and Wireless Network Connection adapters. Disabling just the Bluetooth still resulted in long run times but disabling both did the trick. I am not running any VPN or virtual networks. Thanks again for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Open the Cygwin terminal.

```
mpicc --version

mpirun --version
```

If not execute, follow the document below.[Document](https://github.com/lukasMega/other/wiki/mpi_clion_win)

**2.** Try turning off Bluetooth and test the operation speed.

**3.** Try closing the Wifi and test the operation speed (you can connect to the wired internete)

**4.** Open C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
add line

```
127.0.0.1 localhost cygdrive wpad
```

and test the operation speed.

**5.** If you have a virtual network like VirtualBox or similar, turn off the control panel and test the operation speed.

**6.** If possible, uninstall VirtualBox completely. Restart your computer and test the operation speed.

**7.** Try turning off the Windows Firewall and test the operating speed.

The above steps solved both the "tcp_peer_send_blocking: send () to socket 12 failed: transport endpoint is not connected" error and the slowness problem for Windows 10 - Cygwin.