# Is running a Windows .EXE inherently slower via Cygwin than via BAT?

Tags: windows, performance, batch-file, cygwin

We are running a Windows .EXE file via a Cygwin script and are encountering performance issues.  I have seen various posts about Cygwin performance issues, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512892/how-to-speed-up-cygwin), one of whose [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512892/how-to-speed-up-cygwin#2519769) delves enough into Cygwin internals to make me think there could be a problem.  However, these posts do seem to be more about startup time, tab completion, etc. Before we launch on a benchmarking witch hunt, I was hoping to ask: is there any intrinsic reason why a Windows .EXE could run slower if kicked off from Cygwin vs. BAT?

Comment: If you are seeing high CPU load, that might indicate a runaway thread, which could conceivably be caused by a bug in your program in combination with some difference in the way Cygwin launches it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the actual program, no.

Housekeeping and stuff *before* running the program may vary. Cmd probably calls `CreateProcess` directly. Cygwin's bash may first do argument parsing, wildcard expansion, fork via Cygwin's slow implementation and call `exec` with the parsed arguments, which Cygwin has to piece together into a string again to pass to `CreateProcess`. But in the end, a new process is created which has no ties to its parent anymore. So how fast your program runs entirely depends on that program, not on who launched it.

Comment: There's no difference, e.g., in the way the standard handles are set up?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I wouldn't know that, but that would only affect input and output via them, not the speed at which the program runs, wouldn't it?

Comment: Typically, yes, but a sufficiently buggy program might behave differently depending on the standard handles.  It wouldn't be my first or even my second guess, but I wouldn't rule it out entirely.  :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Well, there's always situations like [these](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21947452/73070) ;-).