# How make cygwin faster?

Tags: cygwin

I have to use cygwin on Windows but altough (like many users complain) the boot is fast, the execution of commands is very, very, very slow. When run on Linux partition it takes at least one tenth of the time. Is there some way to make it work faster? I followed the steps found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512892/how-to-speed-up-cygwin) (second answer) but it didn't work.

Comment: Usually a specific example of what are you referring to is useful to provide specific comments.

Answer (score 1):

In Cygwin what is slow is the execution of the `fork` call. As Microsoft systems do not provide the tools to easily mimic a POSIX fork, Cygwin DLL implements a lot of trick to execute a fork and that makes the full process slow.

Running a single program that does not fork is as fast as a normal Windows program.